# disable mongoEmbeddedServer at test environment

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm using `embedmongo-spring` only for dev purposes. I have a problem using it on my test server as it is failing downloading the embeddedmongo zip file (not a lot of disk space), but anyways, I don't need it to be downloaded as I'm using a real mongoDB server for testing.

The problem is that spring automatically trying to create the embeddedMongoServer:

> 11:10:51.998 [main] WARN  o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext -
>   Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
>   refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'embeddedMongoServer' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/embedded/EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodExecutable]: Factory
>   method 'embeddedMongoServer' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: could not create dir
>   /users//.embedmongo/extracted/Linux-B64--3.2.2 11:10:52.009
>   [main] INFO  o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener -

The only place I'm using the embedded mongo is at some class named `MongoDevConfiguration` which annotated with `@Profile("dev")` (and the output above is for the active profile `test`)

How can I guide spring not to create the embeddedMongoServer on the test server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class)
```